# Simple way to detect text in a PDF highlighted by a user and interact with it programmatically?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm trying to write a little application for my own use. This'll involve first loading a PDF and displaying it in a GUI for me to browse. Then, I want to manually select certain portions of text (like you would highlight in a browser) and run code using the selected text as input. Ideally, the application has support for keyboard inputs as well for text input and hotkeying - but per my understanding most GUI toolkits should include this anyways.

What are some modules that can do this? I'd prefer methods in Python as that's what my backend is written in. However, I've looked at modules like PyMuPDF and Tkinter and couldn't find a way to implement the highlighting portion. Other options like HTML/Javascript would also work for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: SO is not meant to write code for you. Try on your side and come back with a specific coding problem we can help yo usolve.

Comment: I'm happy to write the code myself but was just hoping for pointers towards what modules to use. I've looked for modules with the functionality I need but haven't found any so far.

Comment: Such an answer would be opinion based, which is not allowed on SO. Try with one, come back with a specific problem and we will gladly help you on that.

Comment: I see, I'll have another look around and test a few things first then.